# How to rearrange an array based on priority?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of clothing sizes coming back from an API but in random order. I would want to sort it by having first few values(if they exist) being: XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL, XXXL, and then the rest of the values in whatever order they are coming down from the API.

I want to rearrange the values array of objects to the above sorting order.

values.label is what is supposed to be used here to do that.

```
let apiResponse = {
   "id":"filter.v.option.size",
   "label":"Size",
   "type":"LIST",
   "values":[
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.1",
         "label":"1",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"1\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.2",
         "label":"2",
         "count":5,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"2\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.3",
         "label":"3",
         "count":6,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.3-5",
         "label":"3.5",
         "count":16,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.4",
         "label":"4",
         "count":161,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.4-5",
         "label":"4.5",
         "count":156,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.5",
         "label":"5",
         "count":316,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.5-5",
         "label":"5.5",
         "count":285,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.6",
         "label":"6",
         "count":408,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.6-5",
         "label":"6.5",
         "count":363,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7",
         "label":"7",
         "count":556,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-125",
         "label":"7.125",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7.125\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-25",
         "label":"7.25",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7.25\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-5",
         "label":"7.5",
         "count":538,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.8",
         "label":"8",
         "count":694,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"8\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.8-5",
         "label":"8.5",
         "count":668,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"8.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.9",
         "label":"9",
         "count":709,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"9\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.9-5",
         "label":"9.5",
         "count":658,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"9.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.10",
         "label":"10",
         "count":676,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"10\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.10-5",
         "label":"10.5",
         "count":605,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"10.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.11",
         "label":"11",
         "count":623,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"11\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.11-5",
         "label":"11.5",
         "count":507,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"11.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.12",
         "label":"12",
         "count":601,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"12\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.12-5",
         "label":"12.5",
         "count":62,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"12.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.13",
         "label":"13",
         "count":476,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"13\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.13-5",
         "label":"13.5",
         "count":8,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"13.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.14",
         "label":"14",
         "count":191,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"14\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.14-5",
         "label":"14.5",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"14.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.15",
         "label":"15",
         "count":86,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"15\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.16",
         "label":"16",
         "count":12,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"16\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.17",
         "label":"17",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"17\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.18",
         "label":"18",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"18\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.30",
         "label":"30",
         "count":7,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"30\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.32",
         "label":"32",
         "count":12,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"32\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.34",
         "label":"34",
         "count":7,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"34\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.36",
         "label":"36",
         "count":16,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"36\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.36-5",
         "label":"36.5",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"36.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.37",
         "label":"37",
         "count":5,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"37\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.37-5",
         "label":"37.5",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"37.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.38",
         "label":"38",
         "count":6,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"38\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.38-5",
         "label":"38.5",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"38.5\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.39",
         "label":"39",
         "count":4,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"39\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.40",
         "label":"40",
         "count":10,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"40\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.41",
         "label":"41",
         "count":12,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"41\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.42",
         "label":"42",
         "count":9,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"42\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.43",
         "label":"43",
         "count":9,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"43\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.44",
         "label":"44",
         "count":14,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"44\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.45",
         "label":"45",
         "count":8,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"45\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.46",
         "label":"46",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"46\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.48",
         "label":"48",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"48\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.59",
         "label":"59",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"59\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.4-xl",
         "label":"4 (XL)",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4 (XL)\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-1-2",
         "label":"7 1/2",
         "count":10,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 1\\/2\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-1-4",
         "label":"7 1/4",
         "count":10,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 1\\/4\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-1-8",
         "label":"7 1/8",
         "count":10,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 1\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-3-4",
         "label":"7 3/4",
         "count":10,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 3\\/4\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-3-8",
         "label":"7 3/8",
         "count":10,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 3\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-5-8",
         "label":"7 5/8",
         "count":10,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 5\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7-7-8",
         "label":"7 7/8",
         "count":10,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 7\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.3-4",
         "label":"3/4",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3\\/4\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.3-8",
         "label":"3/8",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.5-8",
         "label":"5/8",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.6c",
         "label":"6C",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6C\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7c",
         "label":"7C",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7C\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.8c",
         "label":"8C",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"8C\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.9c",
         "label":"9C",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"9C\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.10c",
         "label":"10C",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"10C\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.2k",
         "label":"2K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"2K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.3k",
         "label":"3K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.4k",
         "label":"4K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.5k",
         "label":"5K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.6k",
         "label":"6K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7k",
         "label":"7K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.8k",
         "label":"8K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"8K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.9k",
         "label":"9K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"9K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.10k",
         "label":"10K",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"10K\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.2xl",
         "label":"2XL",
         "count":177,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"2XL\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.3xl",
         "label":"3XL",
         "count":52,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3XL\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.2xs",
         "label":"2XS",
         "count":38,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"2XS\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.4-5y",
         "label":"4.5Y",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4.5Y\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.5y",
         "label":"5Y",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5Y\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.5-5y",
         "label":"5.5Y",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5.5Y\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.6y",
         "label":"6Y",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6Y\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.6-5y",
         "label":"6.5Y",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6.5Y\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.7y",
         "label":"7Y",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7Y\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.l",
         "label":"L",
         "count":393,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"L\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.large",
         "label":"Large",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"Large\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.m",
         "label":"M",
         "count":397,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"M\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.medium",
         "label":"Medium",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"Medium\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.ns",
         "label":"NS",
         "count":3,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"NS\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.o-s",
         "label":"O/S",
         "count":57,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"O\\/S\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.s",
         "label":"S",
         "count":388,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"S\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.s-m",
         "label":"S-M",
         "count":1,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"S-M\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.small",
         "label":"Small",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"Small\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.xl",
         "label":"XL",
         "count":323,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XL\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.xlarge",
         "label":"XLarge",
         "count":2,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XLarge\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.xs",
         "label":"XS",
         "count":185,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XS\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.xxl",
         "label":"XXL",
         "count":9,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XXL\"}}"
      },
      {
         "id":"filter.v.option.size.xxs",
         "label":"XXS",
         "count":21,
         "input":"{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XXS\"}}"
      }
   ]
}
```

This what I did, which worked when the values I needed existed. It obviously broke when they didn't exist. Where can I go from here?
By broke I mean, I am hardcoding the indexes here to those specific values. If the api response comes back without those specific sizes, then the code breaks.

For Example: XXS in on index 0, XS is on index 1 and S is on index 2.
If XS doesn't exist then it doesn't work out.

```
var newSortedArray = [];
        var restOfArray = [];
        var joinedArray = [];
        await apiResponse.values.forEach((value) => {

          if(value.label == "XXS") {
            newSortedArray[0] = value;
          }
          else if (value.label == "XS") {
            newSortedArray[1] = value;
          }
          else if (value.label == "S") {
            newSortedArray[2] = value;
          } 
          else if (value.label == "M") {
            newSortedArray[3] = value;
          }
          else if (value.label == "L") {
            newSortedArray[4] = value;
          }
          else if (value.label == "XL") {
            newSortedArray[5] = value;
          }
          else if (value.label == "XXL") {
            newSortedArray[6] = value;
          }
          else if (value.label == "XXXL") {
            newSortedArray[7] = value;
          } 
          else {
            restOfArray.push(value);
          }
        })
        var concatedArray = newSortedArray.concat(restOfArray);

        await this.filters.forEach((filter) => {
          if(filter.label == "Size") {
            filter.values = concatedArray;
          }
        })
```

Comment: What you mean broke?

Comment: edited the above

Comment: 1) Do we really need to see all of your data? Please make it more concise. 2) You are storing JSON in your data. Is this on purpose?

Comment: please add a shorter set of data. where is the wanted size, you are talking about?

Comment: you can get rid of the empty elements of the new array by: `let concatedArray = newSortedArray.filter(i => i).concat(restOfArray);`

Comment: This above line of code worked. Could you explain this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to win any prizes for efficiency, but should be fairly straightforward to follow.

```js
let data = apiResponse().values
let priority = ['XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL', '*']

// 1. create arrays for each priority
let buckets = priority.reduce((agg,label)=>(agg[label]=[], agg),{})

// 2. assign objects to corresponding array
data.forEach(datum=>{
  let collection = buckets?.[datum?.label] || buckets['*']
  collection.push(datum)
})

// 3. recombine after
let sortedData = priority.map(label=>buckets[label]).flat()
console.log(sortedData)


function apiResponse() {
  return {
    "id": "filter.v.option.size",
    "label": "Size",
    "type": "LIST",
    "values": [{
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.1",
        "label": "1",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"1\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.2",
        "label": "2",
        "count": 5,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"2\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.3",
        "label": "3",
        "count": 6,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.3-5",
        "label": "3.5",
        "count": 16,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.4",
        "label": "4",
        "count": 161,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.4-5",
        "label": "4.5",
        "count": 156,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.5",
        "label": "5",
        "count": 316,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.5-5",
        "label": "5.5",
        "count": 285,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.6",
        "label": "6",
        "count": 408,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.6-5",
        "label": "6.5",
        "count": 363,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7",
        "label": "7",
        "count": 556,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-125",
        "label": "7.125",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7.125\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-25",
        "label": "7.25",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7.25\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-5",
        "label": "7.5",
        "count": 538,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.8",
        "label": "8",
        "count": 694,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"8\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.8-5",
        "label": "8.5",
        "count": 668,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"8.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.9",
        "label": "9",
        "count": 709,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"9\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.9-5",
        "label": "9.5",
        "count": 658,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"9.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.10",
        "label": "10",
        "count": 676,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"10\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.10-5",
        "label": "10.5",
        "count": 605,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"10.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.11",
        "label": "11",
        "count": 623,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"11\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.11-5",
        "label": "11.5",
        "count": 507,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"11.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.12",
        "label": "12",
        "count": 601,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"12\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.12-5",
        "label": "12.5",
        "count": 62,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"12.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.13",
        "label": "13",
        "count": 476,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"13\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.13-5",
        "label": "13.5",
        "count": 8,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"13.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.14",
        "label": "14",
        "count": 191,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"14\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.14-5",
        "label": "14.5",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"14.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.15",
        "label": "15",
        "count": 86,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"15\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.16",
        "label": "16",
        "count": 12,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"16\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.17",
        "label": "17",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"17\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.18",
        "label": "18",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"18\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.30",
        "label": "30",
        "count": 7,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"30\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.32",
        "label": "32",
        "count": 12,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"32\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.34",
        "label": "34",
        "count": 7,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"34\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.36",
        "label": "36",
        "count": 16,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"36\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.36-5",
        "label": "36.5",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"36.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.37",
        "label": "37",
        "count": 5,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"37\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.37-5",
        "label": "37.5",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"37.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.38",
        "label": "38",
        "count": 6,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"38\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.38-5",
        "label": "38.5",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"38.5\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.39",
        "label": "39",
        "count": 4,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"39\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.40",
        "label": "40",
        "count": 10,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"40\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.41",
        "label": "41",
        "count": 12,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"41\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.42",
        "label": "42",
        "count": 9,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"42\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.43",
        "label": "43",
        "count": 9,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"43\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.44",
        "label": "44",
        "count": 14,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"44\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.45",
        "label": "45",
        "count": 8,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"45\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.46",
        "label": "46",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"46\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.48",
        "label": "48",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"48\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.59",
        "label": "59",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"59\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.4-xl",
        "label": "4 (XL)",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4 (XL)\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-1-2",
        "label": "7 1/2",
        "count": 10,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 1\\/2\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-1-4",
        "label": "7 1/4",
        "count": 10,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 1\\/4\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-1-8",
        "label": "7 1/8",
        "count": 10,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 1\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-3-4",
        "label": "7 3/4",
        "count": 10,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 3\\/4\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-3-8",
        "label": "7 3/8",
        "count": 10,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 3\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-5-8",
        "label": "7 5/8",
        "count": 10,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 5\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7-7-8",
        "label": "7 7/8",
        "count": 10,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7 7\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.3-4",
        "label": "3/4",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3\\/4\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.3-8",
        "label": "3/8",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.5-8",
        "label": "5/8",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5\\/8\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.6c",
        "label": "6C",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6C\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7c",
        "label": "7C",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7C\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.8c",
        "label": "8C",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"8C\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.9c",
        "label": "9C",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"9C\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.10c",
        "label": "10C",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"10C\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.2k",
        "label": "2K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"2K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.3k",
        "label": "3K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.4k",
        "label": "4K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.5k",
        "label": "5K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.6k",
        "label": "6K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7k",
        "label": "7K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.8k",
        "label": "8K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"8K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.9k",
        "label": "9K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"9K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.10k",
        "label": "10K",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"10K\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.2xl",
        "label": "2XL",
        "count": 177,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"2XL\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.3xl",
        "label": "3XL",
        "count": 52,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"3XL\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.2xs",
        "label": "2XS",
        "count": 38,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"2XS\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.4-5y",
        "label": "4.5Y",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"4.5Y\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.5y",
        "label": "5Y",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5Y\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.5-5y",
        "label": "5.5Y",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"5.5Y\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.6y",
        "label": "6Y",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6Y\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.6-5y",
        "label": "6.5Y",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"6.5Y\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.7y",
        "label": "7Y",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"7Y\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.l",
        "label": "L",
        "count": 393,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"L\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.large",
        "label": "Large",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"Large\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.m",
        "label": "M",
        "count": 397,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"M\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.medium",
        "label": "Medium",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"Medium\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.ns",
        "label": "NS",
        "count": 3,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"NS\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.o-s",
        "label": "O/S",
        "count": 57,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"O\\/S\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.s",
        "label": "S",
        "count": 388,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"S\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.s-m",
        "label": "S-M",
        "count": 1,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"S-M\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.small",
        "label": "Small",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"Small\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.xl",
        "label": "XL",
        "count": 323,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XL\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.xlarge",
        "label": "XLarge",
        "count": 2,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XLarge\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.xs",
        "label": "XS",
        "count": 185,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XS\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.xxl",
        "label": "XXL",
        "count": 9,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XXL\"}}"
      },
      {
        "id": "filter.v.option.size.xxs",
        "label": "XXS",
        "count": 21,
        "input": "{\"variantOption\":{\"name\":\"size\",\"value\":\"XXS\"}}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```